# Merging several RFQ's into one purchase order in OpenERP

Tags: erp, openerp

I have several requests for quotations for the same supplier. Can I merge them into one purchase order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To merge quotations, just highlight them all in the list and click on the Action button. That will display a message describing what kinds of quotations can be merged. Click Merge orders, and a new window opens with the merged quotations in a list.